# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry Android

Tags: android, xmpp, android-manifest, ejabberd

I have been working on a chatting kind of application using xmpp ejabbered. I wanted a signed apk of the app, so i tried getting one but I got the following error. Previously i was getting same error with com.parse library so i removed the library from libs folder and now this error. I searched on net and many people got that error but their libraries are different so I tried implementing that but still wasn't successful.
This is my app level build.gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mchat.sunil.com.mchat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
    compile 'org.jitsi:org.otr4j:0.22'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'

}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

The error which i'm getting is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jxmpp/stringprep/simple/SimpleXmppStringprep.class
Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Solutions which i tried is excluding it with different libraries one by one.

```
    all*.exclude group: 'jxmpp', module: 'smack-tcp'
    all*.exclude group: 'jxmpp', module: 'smack-android-extensions'
    all*.exclude group: 'jxmpp', module: 'parse-android'
    all*.exclude group: 'jxmpp', module: 'org.otr4j'
```

but still couldn't find the proper solution. Can anyone help me with this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should try `exclude group: 'org.jxampp'`. group needs the full prefix. In your case, group would be `org.jxampp` and module would be `jxmpp-util-cache`. Exclude that from `smack-android-extensions` dependency and it should work

Comment: @th3pat3l   Nope, I tried but it still not working same error again.